# How to put image and link under PropertyPane Description field for the web part in SPFx?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, react, spfx-custom-property-pane

I was trying with using `React.CreateElement` in the description field and changing the type for the description field from string to `IPropertyPaneField` in the interface, but this declaration exists in `index-internal.ts` which is in node modules.

Please let me know how we can overwrite or change the type for the description field so it can take up the `React.CreateElement` function?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check below web part sample in Github repository where author added hyperlink on web part property pane using custom HTML:

[Script editor web part for modern pages built in React](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-script-editor)

Specially check these two files:

1. [PropertyPaneLogo.ts](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/main/samples/react-script-editor/src/webparts/scriptEditor/PropertyPaneLogo.ts) - custom HTML for hyperlink is written here
2. [ScriptEditorWebPart.ts](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/main/samples/react-script-editor/src/webparts/scriptEditor/ScriptEditorWebPart.ts) - Imported custom HTML & overridden the property pane method in web part

---

You may also use the [@pnp/spfx-property-controls](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/) in web part for customizing the property pane.

Check this control which might be helpful to you: [PropertyPaneWebPartInformation control](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/controls/PropertyPaneWebPartInformation/)

Example output of this control:

[image]